# Running flyway migration on a DB with existing tables

Tags: flyway

I am running flyway migrations on a postgres DB with existing tables. In doing so flyway threw this error

```sh
Found non-empty schema(s) "public" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
```

After reading the docs on [baselineOnMigrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/baselineOnMigrate), all we need to do is toggle this to `true` and we should be able to complete the migrations.

Need clarity on enabling this feature:
do we set `FLYWAY_BASELINE_ON_MIGRATE` to `TRUE` only once and when the schema history table is created we can turn it back to `FALSE`? Or do we have to persist the `TRUE` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd set it only once. That approach is really only used where Flyway takes all its parameters from the configuration file...it is just intended for a single use (e.g. just for one specific copy of a database, out of many). Normally, you baseline from an action at the command line like this:

```
Flyway baseline  @FlywayArgs -baselineVersion='1.3.1' -baselineDescription='Existing version of MyDatabase'
```

This article is using a SQL Server database rather than Postgres but might give a good idea of how flyway baselines work: https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/flyway-baselines-and-consolidations.